# Stop posting html tags in form using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I have a form, In which I want user couldn't enter html tags or script and submit form in angularjs.
for this I'm using `$sanitize` but it's not working.

this is my form

```
<html>

  <head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="birthdayToDo" ng-controller="main">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <form name="testForm" ng-submit="submitForm(testForm.$valid)" novalidate>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="testText"/>
        <p ng-show="testForm.name.$dirty && testForm.name.$invalid && testForm.submitted" class="error">
          Invalid Input
        </p>
      <input type="submit"  value="Save"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

as soon as he enter invalid input, It shows an error message. 
I'm using this concept

```
$scope.SanitizeDemo=function() {
   return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.testText);
   };
```

[**My Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gfhK33GNfm1kXBTuZLgj?p=preview)

Comment: What do you want? you want to prevent the user from entering html tags? why?

Comment: @WayneEllery: yes. I don't want user to input html tag or scripts . like if he want to enter <script>..some js code</script> , then form should be invalid. and also I'm restricted to use regex.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: because If he enter some script in Name field then when showing name list it will show script instead of a valid name.

Comment: The best practice for this is to instead use a whitelist. That is a regex which will say what characters are allowed rather than a black list saying which characters/strings aren't allowed. You should use a whitelist

Comment: @WayneEllery: Thank you. But is there any way so that after submitting a form I can get only rendered text. like if he input <p style="color:red">Hello </p>  then only Hello should be saved. btw if it not posible then I'll sure use regex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68257/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-amit-kumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. Use a whitelist regular expression in both angularjs as well as your backend to validate the input.

For security, best practice is for each field to have a regular expression which will only allow certain valid input. A simple one for name would be `/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i`. This would be on the server side to prevent any data being sent that was not valid. This could also be placed on the client side to also validate.

By default Angularjs encodes output when using `{{}}` to protect against XSS, so `<b>abs</b>` will appear as is and this is what you want from a security point of view to prevent third party script from executing on your page.

In some cases you may want to allow output of html and allow it safely but in which case you can use `ng-bind-html` with `ng-sanitize` and don't need to use `$sce` directly.