# regEx for matching html tags in angular2

Tags: regex, angular

I have a page in angular 1.3 in the below pattern is used for matching html tags in the password .The regEx check if user has entered "<" or ">".

```
 <input ng-model='user.password' type="password" 
        name='password' class="form-control input-lg b  text-md" 
        placeholder='New Password' required 
        ng-maxlength="25" ng-minlength="6" ng-pattern="/^[^<\>]+$/">

<div ng-show="resetPasswordForm.password.$error.pattern" class="text-danger sxo_validate_msg text-sm">
    Html tags not allowed
</div>
```

The same code when i use in angular2 the error message always shows irrespective of whether i enter <> or not.

Below is the code in angular2

```
    <input [(ngModel)]='user.password' id="password" type="password" 
           name='password' class="form-control input-lg b  text-md"
           placeholder='New Password' required maxlength="25" minlength="6" 
           pattern="/^[^<\>]+$/" #password="ngModel">

   <div *ngIf="password.hasError('pattern')" class="text-danger sxo_validate_msg text-sm">
         Html tags not allowed
   </div>
```

Please Guide.The error should show only if the user has entered "<" ">".

Comment: Do you need a template driven form?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27794200/5695162